# How to get the REST Trace using the DocuSign C# Client SDK?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Is there a way to get the REST Trace programmatically using the updated version of the [DocuSign C# Client SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) (DocuSign.eSign)?

The previous version of the SDK (DocuSign.Integrations.Client) had a RestTrace property that could be accessed from the Envelope if you set the proper setting:

```
RestSettings.Instance.RestTracing = true;
```

For example, after the call

```
// create envelope and send it
bool result = envelope.Create(documentData, filename);
```

you could access the `envelope.RestTrace` property to get the full API request sent to DocuSign.

The new EnvelopeDefinition and EnvelopesApi class don't appear to have a similar property. Is there a way to access that information that I am missing?

The updated SDK call looks like:

```
// create envelope and send it
// |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelope);
```

`envelope` is defined as a `EnvelopeDefinition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the beta Recipe Framework app to easily see your API calls and responses from your app.

See the "API Log" menu item in the navbar.

See the [Github repo.](https://github.com/docusign/esignature-recipes-python)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to retrieve the API logs using this app running in Heroku. It's not exactly what I was thinking when I asked the question, but it accomplishes what I needed to do.